# ES6 destructuring object data from @Input in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, destructuring

Is it possible to destructure complex data that are passed to @Input like we can do in ES6 variable destructuring? Lets say i want to pass this object {a: 1, b: 2} into something like const {a,b} = obj, but not using init hook. Something like this @Input {a, b} = passedObject

Comment: Using setter: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqvbft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: but I still need to declare the properties in the component?